# How to add the results from checkbutton and text entries on GUI into dictionary in key:value format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox, tkinter-entry

Trying to create a simple shopping list app, that will have user check the checkbox then enter the number of items. The button press should output a name with the number of item. for example, Apples 10, 1 banan etc. I would like to grow the fruits dictionary and later add other items to GUI, like meats/fish, general etc.

I thought the logical way would be to create a dictionary {key:value} where key would be the name of the checkbox, and a value will be the number inside entry text box.

Could you please show me how to do this? Thanks!

tried following some examples but could not understand how to extract a text="Apples" from checkbox and add this as a key into dictionary. Also played with lambda as output but nothing really materialized because all examples alreaddy had a dictionary created. 
here is my example.

```
from tkinter import *

item_list = []
items_dict = {}

    # mget gets output from checkboxes and prints results
def mget():
    print(apples.get(), pears.get(), bananas.get(),apricots.get())
    print(apples_qnty.get(),pears_qnty.get(), bananas_qnty.get(), 
    apricots_qnty.get())
    #item_list.append(apples.get)

 window = Tk()


apples = IntVar()
chk_apples = Checkbutton(window,text="Apples", 
variable=apples).grid(row=1,sticky=W) 
apples_qnty = StringVar()
apples_qnty = Entry(width=3)
apples_qnty.grid(column=1, row = 1)
item_list.append("Apples")

pears = IntVar()
chk_pears = Checkbutton(window,text="Pears", 
variable=pears).grid(row=2,sticky=W)
pears_qnty = StringVar()
pears_qnty = Entry(width=3)
pears_qnty.grid(column=1, row = 2)
item_list.append("Pears")

bananas = IntVar()
Checkbutton(window,text="Bananas", 
variable=bananas).grid(row=3,sticky=W)
bananas_qnty = StringVar()
bananas_qnty = Entry(width=3)
bananas_qnty.grid(column=1, row = 3)
item_list.append("Bananas")


apricots = IntVar()
Checkbutton(window,text="Apricots", 
variable=apricots).grid(row=4,sticky=W)

apricots_qnty = StringVar()
apricots_qnty = Entry(width=3)
apricots_qnty.grid(column=1, row = 4)
item_list.append("Apricots")

print(item_list)  # just to see list


Button(window,text="print check box states", command = mget).grid(row=5,sticky=W)
Button(window,text="exit", command =window.destroy).grid(row=5,sticky=E)

window.mainloop()
```

I would like the program to do the following:
user checks on checkbuttons and enters numbers of items. 
pressing the button would output the items selected. 
For example, Apples 4, Bananas 1 etc... 
If the checkbutton is unchecked then don't output anything.

Answer (score 0):

The variable parameter in each of your Checkbutton functions is currently IntVar(). This means that when it is checked it returns a value of 1 and when it is unchecked it returns the value of 0.

You can change the variable to a StringVar() and then assign it with a offvalue (unchecked) and onvalue (checked). This will give you scope to decide on what these values can return.

Using apples as an example:

```
#Your current code using IntVar()
    apples = IntVar()
    chk_apples = Checkbutton(window,text="Apples", 
    variable=apples).grid(row=1,sticky=W) 

#Modification using StringVar()
    apples = StringVar()
    chk_apples = Checkbutton(window,text="Apples",
    variable=apples, offvalue="", onvalue="Apples").grid(row=1,sticky=W)
```

By setting the onvalue as "Apples" the checkbutton will return the string variable "Apples".

I can then apply that logic for each of the fruits  and then finally amend the mget function to the below:

```
def mget():

    fruit_list = [apples.get(), pears.get(), bananas.get(), apricots.get()]

    fruit_quantity =[apples_qnty.get(), pears_qnty.get() , bananas_qnty.get(),
    apricots_qnty.get()]

    fruit_dictionary = dict(zip(fruit_list,fruit_quantity)) #combines the two lists by their indices to create a dictionary

    print(fruit_dictionary)
    for keys, values in fruit_dictionary.items():
        if keys == "" or values =="":
            pass
        else:
            print(keys, values)
```

As a side note it would be good practice and improve readability if you assign each get.function to a variable i.e.

```
fruit_apple = apple.get()
```